# Let a group $G$ act on a set $S$ and let $x \in S$. Prove that $G_x =\{g \in G ∶ g \cdot x=x\}$ is a subgroup of $G$.

Tags: group-theory

> Let a group $G$ act on a set $S$ and let $x \in S$. Prove that $G_x =\{g \in G ∶ g \cdot x=x\}$ is a subgroup of $G$.

I suppose you use the standard way of proving a subgroup: show it is nonempty and then show that $ab^{-1} \in G_x$. Need help showing this with an action involved. It is probably simple but seeing it would help a lot.

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: In literature, the group $G_x$ defined, is called the **stabilizer** of $G$ by $x$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume $a,b \in G_x$.

It follows that $a \cdot x = x$ and $b \cdot x = x$.

Applying $b^{-1}$ on both sides of the second equation, it follows that
$$b^{-1} \cdot (b \cdot x) = b^{-1} \cdot x
$$
$$(b^{-1} b) \cdot x = b^{-1} \cdot x
$$
$$1 \cdot x = b^{-1} \cdot x
$$
$$x = b^{-1} \cdot x
$$
And, finally,
$$ab^{-1} \cdot x = a \cdot (b^{-1} \cdot x) = a \cdot x = x
$$

Comment: Ah yes see I did not know how to incorporate the action into everything. Thank you this is really helpful.

Comment: This doesn't mention that $G_x$ is nonempty.

Answer (score 2):

Since $G$ acts on $S$, $1 \cdot x = x$ (where $1$ is the identity element of $G$). But this precisely means that $1 \in G_x$, i.e. $G_x$ is non-empty. Can you continue from here?

Comment: I am having a hard time thinking of how to do the rest with an action. Without an action yes I can but this simple change makes me unsure.